# How can I get just the parent item and not the children in an invoice

Tags: magento, invoice, orders

I'm trying to make our packing slips and invoices more useful, especially when we have bundled products.

How can I show just the parent item and not the children in an invoice?

When I use `$order->getAllItems()` I get two lines in output:

```
parent-child sku

child sku
```

If I use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()` I only get the parent, which is what I want.

```
Parent sku
```

Now  `invoice->getAllItems` with  produces the two lines  Parent-Child and Child
But `invoice->getAllVisibleItems` with  produces no lines

So it will show qty and amt on the invoice twice. not good for customers or packers.

```
<?php
require_once '../mage1/app/Mage.php';
require_once('Zend/Pdf.php');  
$app = Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true); 

$orderId = '500000555' ;  

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    echo 'ITEM: ' . $item->getSku() . '<br />';
}
//vs invoice
echo 'Invoice Section <br />' ;

if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    echo 'Order has invoices'  . '<br />';
foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_eachInvoice) {

    foreach ($_eachInvoice->getAllVisibleItems as $invitem){
    //foreach ($_eachInvoice->getAllItems() as $invitem){
        //echo 'Object <br />';
        var_dump(get_object_vars($invitem));
        //print_r($invitem);  echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />';
        echo 'INVOICE ITEM: ' . $invitem->getSku() . '<br />';
        }
    }
} else { echo 'no invoices' ; };
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: I'm expecting getItemCollection to behave the same with invoices as with orders, but it does not.  It returns parents and children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use `$invoice->getAllVisibleItems()` and for order use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`

Just a word of Advise try to use `get_class_method`, `get_class`, `get_class_vars` for getting familiar with a class.

Comment: Sam, I will use the the `get_class` & etc, thanks for the tip. Working with the `getAllVisibleItems` for invoices now.

Comment: I updated code with Sam's suggestion for invoice. Workds for order but shows no skus for invoices. Edited code above.

Comment: sorry, Getting close but the order works but not the invoice. I posted the code in case I'm doing something wrong that someone could spot.  I left in a commented getAllItems for testing between the two..

Comment: @Dan I hope u got it working, I see a typo `$_eachInvoice->getAllVisibleItems` should be `$_eachInvoice->getAllVisibleItems()` its the method call.

Comment: and for a cart?